# Jooq coalesce on collection using DSL

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to use Jooq's coalesce function using the DSL on a collection of fields (or their extension).

However, Jooq's coalesce function accepts input in the form of varags, which I'm having trouble with since my translation from a collection to varargs seems to be breaking the input.

```
List<Field<?>> fields = List.of(DSL.field(DSL.name("a", "b")), DSL.field(DSL.name("c", "d")));
DSL.coalesce(fields.get(0), fields.get(1));  // this works as each field is of type TableFieldImpl
DSL.coalesce(fields.toArray(new Field<?>[0]));     // this throws "Type interface org.jooq.Field is not supported in dialect DEFAULT"
```

I tried a few options in the toArray init, but nothing really works.

Worth noting that the runtime type of the fields is TableFieldImpl

Answer (score 1):

I actually missed a important part - the 1st arg is the mandatory first element (either literal as T Value or columnar as Field), the rest is the list of args.

so was able to fix it this way

```
    List<Field<?>> fields = List.of(DSL.field(DSL.name("a", "b")), DSL.field(DSL.name("c", "d")));
    Field<? extends Object> first = fields.get(0);
    Field<?>[] others = fields.stream().skip(1).toList().toArray(new Field<?>[0]);
    DSL.coalesce(first, others);
```

maybe it helps others...